# ZF2 Currency Format

Tags: php, zend-framework2, currency

I am using ZF2 for my project. And this is an e-commerce site. So I am dealing with currencies.

In ZF2 there is a view helper named `currencyFormat()`

I am from Turkey so my main currency format is TRY (This is the ISO code of Turkish Lira). But in Turkey we do not use TRY as Currency icon. The icons are "$" for USD, € for "EUR" and "TL" for Turkish Lira (TRY).

So when I format a currency for TRY I am doing it like this in view script:

```
<?php
echo $this->currencyFormat(245.40, 'TRY', 'tr_TR');
?>
```

The result of this code is "245.40 TRY". But it has to be "245.40 **TL**"

Is there a way to solve this? I do not want to use replacement function.

Comment: What happens when you replace TRY with TL?

Comment: It does not print any think. Since the helper uses INTL extension, It only accepts ISO codes of the currencies.

Comment: `TL` would be no official ISO 4217 currency code indicator and therefore will not work. I would consider this behavior a bug in the PHP Core then, if this is really the case. I don't know about turkey though, but if its really TL and not TRY, then you should file a bug report!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing when you say `I do not want to use replacement function` you mean it would be laborious to do a `str_replace` every time you call the helper. The solution would be to replace the helper with your own. Here's a quick how to

First create a helper of your own which extends the existing helper and handles the replacement if necessary...

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\I18n\View\Helper\CurrencyFormat;

class MyCurrencyFormat extends CurrencyFormat
{
    public function __invoke(
        $number,
        $currencyCode = null,
        $showDecimals = null,
        $locale       = null
    ) {
       // call parent and get the string
       $string = parent::__invoke($number, $currencyCode, $showDecimals, $locale);
       // format to taste and return
       if (FALSE !== strpos($string, 'TRY')) {
           $string = str_replace('TRY', 'TL', $string);
       }
       return $string;
    }
}
```

Then in Module.php, implement the ViewHelperProviderInterface, and provide it with details of your helper

```
//Application/Module.php
class Module implements \Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ViewHelperProviderInterface
{

     public function getViewHelperConfig()
     {
         return array(
             'invokables' => array(
                  // you can either alias it by a different name, and call that, eg $this->mycurrencyformat(...)
                  'mycurrencyformat'  => 'Application\View\Helper\MyCurrencyFormat',
                  // or if you want to ALWAYS use your version of the helper, replace the above line with the one below, 
                  //and all existing calls to $this->currencyformat(...) in your views will be using your version
                  // 'currencyformat'  => 'Application\View\Helper\MyCurrencyFormat',
              ),
         );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 1 March 2012 sign for Turkish Lira is TRY. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_lira

So ZF outputs it right I think.

Comment: ZF is right. However, TRY (2 chars is country, 3rd one represents currency name, which is 'YENI LIRA') is international and ZF is perfectly right. However, we locally use TL and nobody will understand TRY, that's all about it. @Crisp's solution entirely solves it however it is needed.